# Store scheduled tasks in user profile

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, remote-desktop-services, farm

We are currently creating two remote desktop farms for our users.

One farm is for operations staff, and one is for accounts. In both cases, we are using Server 2012 R2 remote desktop deployments with central user profile disks to allow a consistent profile regardless of what server they are connected to.

One application our accounts staff use, is an excel reporting add-in. They schedule reports to run at certain times of the day.
These scheduled reports are essentially just windows tasks.

As the farm they connect to is load balanced across two hosts, they could be logged onto one server or the other. My issue at the moment, is that the scheduled reports will not follow them across servers, so the schedule task is only available to the user if they are connected to the host on which the task was created.

I don't think it will be possible to do this, as when the user logs off their profile will no longer be loaded (hence why tasks are stored centrally), but I am hoping someone can confirm whether or not it is possible to store these scheduled tasks in a users profile instead of the system folder, to allow the tasks to follow them onto different servers.

I have considered trying to sync the tasks across servers using scripts, but then that will mean the task will run multiple times instead of just once, which isn't a workable option.

Comment: If they must use RDS, consider having these users remote into a particular host instead of the farm.

Comment: Yes it's a tricky one, as half the reason we are heavily investigating in the idea of a farm, is to provide some high availability. Should anything happen to that one server, a farm allows them to continue working as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Task Scheduler has no provisions to do what you're asking for in its stock functionality. You'd need to look to third-party software or, as you say, trying to put something together yourself, to get what you want.